# Box2D not simulating

Tags: c++, box2d

I want to start the simulation, but it doesn't work\n
PhysEngine.hpp

```
#include <box2d/box2d.h>
float ticks = 30.0f;
b2Vec2 gravity(0.0, -10.0);
b2World phys_world(gravity);
float timeStep = 1.0f / ticks;
int32 velocityIterations = 8;
int32 positionIterations = 3;



class PhysicObjectStatic {
public:
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    b2Body *body;
    b2PolygonShape shape;
    void init(float x, float y, float width, float height);
};
class PhysicObjectDynamic {
public:
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;

    b2Body* body;
    b2PolygonShape dynamicBox;

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;


    void init(float x, float y, float width, float height);
};
void PhysicObjectDynamic::init(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
    body = phys_world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    dynamicBox.SetAsBox(width, height);
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position.Set(x, y);
    fixtureDef.shape = &dynamicBox;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
}
void PhysicObjectStatic::init(float x, float y, float width, float height) {

    bodyDef.position.Set(x, y);
    body = phys_world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    shape.SetAsBox(width, height);
    body->CreateFixture(&shape, 0.0f);
}
void simulate(b2Body *body) {
    phys_world.Step(timeStep, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
    b2Vec2 position = body->GetPosition();

    float angle = body->GetAngle();
    printf("%4.2f %4.2f %4.2f\n", position.x, position.y, angle);


}
```

main.cpp

```
...
    PhysObjectDynamic object;
    object.init(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 10.0f);
...
while (true) {
simulate(object.body);
}
...
```

And after launching the application, it displays the following

0.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 0.00

I tried to add force in function `simulate` and before phys_world.Step, but it didn`t work. I excepted something like this, like on box2d docs:

0.00 4.00 0.00\n
0.00 3.99 0.00\n
0.00 3.98 0.00\n
...
0.00 1.25 0.00\n
0.00 1.13 0.00\n
0.00 1.01 0.00\n